# Hidden project files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a project in VB

Some files are hidden

Why is that and does it have a purpose?

[image]

Comment: those files won't get compiled/published

Comment: @zgood What is the purpose of adding them?

Comment: Some of those would be 'behind the scenes', auto generated content that you normally don't access or modify directly.

Comment: @startNet Those files have been excluded from the project, or not included. Perhaps they are for unused features, or their code has been incorporated into other files. Looking at the comments in the files or in the [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) commit messages might tell you more.

Comment: @AndrewMorton is correct about the files shown in your screenshot. Additional files which are hidden are designer files i.e. FormName.Designer.vb or project configuration files i.e. AssemblyInfo.vb, Resources.resx. If you happen to drop a new file into your project directory you will get the same behavior.

Comment: @startNet maybe to keep an old or legacy version of a file for reference.